# jQuery DataTable - Enable/disable column filtering on hide/show after initialization dynamically

Tags: jquery, datatables

My first post on Stack Overflow. :)

I have a jQuery DataTable, with a custom dropdown "Hide/show columns" with checkboxes. These are working perfectly. But when I hide a column, I also want it to not be searchable. When I show it again, I want it to be searchable again. Is this possible?

Here is my code:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]', $("#myHideShowDropdown")).change(function () {
    // data-column is just the number of the column
    var column = oTable.column($(this).attr("data-column")); 
    column.visible(!column.visible()); // This works

    // Here I want to to something like 
    // column.searchable(!column.searchable()) 
    // but there is no such thing
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

To toggle column filtering along with visibility, use the code below:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]', $("#myHideShowDropdown")).change(function () {
   var colIdx = $(this).attr("data-column");
   var column = oTable.column(colIdx);
   var isVisible = column.visible();

   column.visible(!isVisible); 
   oTable.settings()[0].aoColumns[colIdx].bSearchable = !isVisible;

   oTable.rows().invalidate().draw(false);
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cpaysba/) for code and demonstration.